# How To Save Content of GTKTextBuffer to a File

Tags: gtk, nxt, lego-mindstorms, anjuta

I'm writing on Ubuntu 12.04 in Anjuta with C and GTK a program. It's a graphical  interface for the nbc (Lego NXT Compiler). I have a GTKTextView. Now I want to save the content of the textview to a file, which could be chosen by a GTKFileChooser. Now I don't know how to get the text from the TextView and write it to the file. How do i do this?

Answer (score 6):

First, get the `GtkTextBuffer` from the `GtkTextView` using `gtk_text_view_get_buffer()`. Then get the start and end *GtkTextIters* from the buffer to use to get the text of the buffer. Finally, write that text to the file using the API of your choice, however, I would recommend `Gio`. Here's a snippet from my old tutorial:

```c
gtk_widget_set_sensitive (text_view, FALSE);
buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (editor->text_view));
gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter (buffer, &start);
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (buffer, &end);
text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (buffer, &start, &end, FALSE);       
gtk_text_buffer_set_modified (buffer, FALSE);
gtk_widget_set_sensitive (editor->text_view, TRUE);

/* set the contents of the file to the text from the buffer */
if (filename != NULL)        
    result = g_file_set_contents (filename, text, -1, &err);
else
    result = g_file_set_contents (editor->filename, text, -1, &err);

if (result == FALSE)
{
    /* error saving file, show message to user */
    error_message (err->message);
    g_error_free (err);
}        

g_free (text);
```

Check out the following API documentation:

1. http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html
2. [http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html)

Comment: By the way, `result` is a gboolean, `buffer` is a GtkTextBuffer, `err` is a GError, and `start`/`end` are GtkTextIter. It's taken from this code: http://www.micahcarrick.com/files/gtk-glade-tutorial/C/main.c

Comment: I implemented the code in my program, but it crashes with Error code 11 (segmentation fault). What's wrong? This is my function:

Comment: Can you paste in the function you actually used?

Comment: Does this solution also take the TAGS into account? What if I use tags and I want to store my rich text to a file?

Answer (score 2):

```
void on_toolbutton3_clicked(GtkToolButton *toolbutton, gpointer data)
{   


    GtkWidget *dialog;
    dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Abspeichern...",
                      NULL,
                      GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE,
                      GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                      GTK_STOCK_SAVE, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                      NULL);
    if (gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
    {
    char *filename;
    char *text;
    GtkTextIter *start;
    GtkTextIter *end;
    gboolean result;
    GError *err;
    filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (dialog));
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive (data, FALSE);
    savebuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (data));
gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter (savebuffer, &start);
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (savebuffer, &end);
text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (savebuffer, &start, &end, FALSE);       
gtk_text_buffer_set_modified (savebuffer, FALSE);
gtk_widget_set_sensitive (data, TRUE);

/* set the contents of the file to the text from the buffer */
if (filename != NULL)        
    result = g_file_set_contents (filename, text, -1, &err);
else
    result = g_file_set_contents (filename, text, -1, &err);

if (result == FALSE)
{
    /* error saving file, show message to user */

}        

g_free (text); 
    }
    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);

}
```

data points on textview1.