# Iterators do not belong to their assigned text buffer

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

This is a bare bones `save_as()` function:

```
gint save_as(GtkWidget *parent, struct buffers B)
{
    GtkWidget *file_chooser = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Save As", GTK_WINDOW(parent), GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE, "Cancel", GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, "Save", GTK_RESPONSE_OK, NULL);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(file_chooser), "Untitled");

    gint response = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(file_chooser));
    switch(response)
    {
        case GTK_RESPONSE_OK:
                GFile *file = g_file_new_for_path(gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(file_chooser)));
                GtkTextIter *start;
                gtk_text_buffer_get_start(B.buffer0, &start);
                GtkTextIter *end;
                gtk_text_buffer_get_end(B.buffer0, &end);
                // program abnormally terminates on the following line
                gchar *contents = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(B.buffer0, &start, &end, FALSE);
                g_file_replace_contents(file, contents, strlen(contents), NULL, FALSE, G_FILE_CREATE_NONE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                g_free(contents);
                gtk_widget_destroy(file_chooser);
                return GTK_RESPONSE_OK;
                break;
        case GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL:
                gtk_widget_destroy(file_chooser);
                return GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL;
    }
    // user pressed X
    gtk_widget_destroy(file_chooser);
    return GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL;
}
```

This is pretty much all we need to diagnose and fix the problem.

Here is the full message I get when I try to click on *File -> Save As...* and then on *Save*:

```
(test:4478): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:56:20.184: Invalid text buffer iterator: either the iterator is uninitialized, or the characters/pixbufs/widgets in the buffer have been modified since the iterator was created.
You must use marks, character numbers, or line numbers to preserve a position across buffer modifications.
You can apply tags and insert marks without invalidating your iterators, but any mutation that affects 'indexable' buffer contents (contents that can be referred to by character offset) will invalidate all outstanding iterators


(test:4478): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 11:56:20.184: gtk_text_buffer_get_text: assertion 'gtk_text_iter_get_buffer (start) == buffer' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

For some reason, it seems that the iterators `start` and `end` do not belong to `B.buffer0`. Apart from [GTK+3 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/), I also followed answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088338/how-to-save-content-of-gtktextbuffer-to-a-file) as a guide.

Why is this happening and how it can be fixed?

---

I also tried changing the following lines:

`gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(B.buffer0, &start);` to `gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(B.buffer0, start);`

`gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(B.buffer0, &end);` to `gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(B.buffer0, end);`

`gchar *contents = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(B.buffer0, &start, &end, FALSE);` to `gchar *contents = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(B.buffer0, start, end, FALSE);`

The only error I get is:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is also supposed to be the correct way to send arguments according to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html).

Also, I tried replacing `contents = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(B.buffer0, start, end, FALSE);` with `contents = gtk_text_iter_get_text(start, end);` but I get the same error.

I also noticed that I get two warnings during compiling after applying those changes:

```
src/save.c:96:5: warning: ‘start’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(B.buffer0, start);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/save.c:98:5: warning: ‘end’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(B.buffer0, end);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This obviously means that `gtk_text_buffer_get_start/end_iter()` fails to associate `start` and `end` with `B.buffer0`, but why? It says that `start` and `end` are passed uninitialized, but isn't that normal since I'm initializing them now? Or I should do something before that?

---

Definition of struct buffer is in a file called `buffer.h`. Here it is (not the whole file, just the struct definition):

```
struct buffers
{
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer0;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer1;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer2;
};
```

The instance I use is:

```
struct buffers Buffer;
```

This is a global variable, so `buffer.h` is included in every file that uses `Buffer`. And for the same purpose (globality), of course it is declared `extern struct buffers Buffer;` in the header file associated with the source file in which it is defined.

This buffer is passed to a function `save_as()` like this:

```
gint response = save_as(main_window, Buffer);
```

*In case you're wondering why I just don't use global variable instead of passing it as a parameter, it is because I can just pass any variable of type `struct buffers` to a `save_file()` and let it do the job, instead of having another function for each `struct buffers` variable.*

---

I tried initializing iterators upon their definition:

```
GtkTextIter *start = NULL;
GtkTextIter *end = NULL;
```

Everything compiles without any warnings. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. Upon clicking *File -> Save As* and then *Save*, the program exits and I get messages:

```
(test:4081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:48:29.843: gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter: assertion 'iter != NULL' failed

(test:4081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:48:29.844: gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter: assertion 'iter != NULL' failed

(test:4081): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:48:29.844: gtk_text_buffer_get_text: assertion 'start != NULL' failed
```

Why is it even important that my `start` and `end` iterators are `NULL` at least in the first two cases? Aren't those two functions supposed to set `start` and `end` iterators to the start and the end of a file, respectively? Therefore, why does it matter to what iterators are set prior to that?

Comment: In gtk2, the correct form ar `gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buf, start);`, `gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buf, start);` and `gtk_text_buffer_get_text([...], buf, start, [...]);` (no `&`). Have you checked that `contents` is not `NULL`?

Comment: @purplepsycho As for the forms, yes I know (this is gtk3 btw). I changed that but I still get an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. As for the `contents`, I can't check that because `gtk_text_buffer_get_text()` never returns.

Comment: Well, how is `struct buffer` defined, and are you sure that `B.buffer0` is a valid `GtkTextBuffer*`?

Comment: @purplepsycho I'll edit my answer to include that information.

Comment: @purplepsycho Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it. It looks like that `GtkTextIter` is a little bit different than most GTK types.

Here is how it should be done:

```
gint save_as(GtkWidget *parent, struct buffers B)
{
    GtkWidget *file_chooser = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Save As", GTK_WINDOW(parent), GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE, "Cancel", GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, "Save", GTK_RESPONSE_OK, NULL);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(file_chooser), "Untitled");

    gint response = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(file_chooser));
    switch(response)
    {
        case GTK_RESPONSE_OK:
                GFile *file = g_file_new_for_path(gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(file_chooser)));
                GtkTextIter start;
                gtk_text_buffer_get_start(B.buffer0, &start);
                GtkTextIter end;
                gtk_text_buffer_get_end(B.buffer0, &end);
                // program abnormally terminates on the following line
                gchar *contents = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(B.buffer0, &start, &end, FALSE);
                g_file_replace_contents(file, contents, strlen(contents), NULL, FALSE, G_FILE_CREATE_NONE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                g_free(contents);
                gtk_widget_destroy(file_chooser);
                return GTK_RESPONSE_OK;
                break;
        case GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL:
                gtk_widget_destroy(file_chooser);
                return GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL;
    }
    // user pressed X
    gtk_widget_destroy(file_chooser);
    return GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL;
}
```

As you can see, the only difference in this code and the code from my question are the following two lines:

**Wrong**

```
GtkTextIter *start;
GtkTextIter *end;
```

**Right**

```
GtkTextIter start;
GtkTextIter end;
```

Most of the GTK types want you to make them pointers, but this one is an exception.